# Format double in engineering notation with fixed number of fractional digits

Tags: java, format

I want to use a `DecimalFormat` that formats numbers in engineering notation (exponent is a multiple of 3) and with a fixed number of fractional digits. The number of fractional digits should be configurable by the pattern.

Is that possible with the `java.text.DecimalFormat` class. 
Is there an alternative?

Here is the test case that outputs 12.345E3 instead of 12.34E3:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##0.00E0");

    String realOutput = df.format(12345);
    String expected = "12.34E3";

    System.out.println(realOutput);
    if (Objects.equals(realOutput, expected))
    {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("Formatted output " + realOutput + " differs from documented output " + expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: [google is your friend](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/java/engNotation.html)

Comment: Google is only your second best friend. Your best friend is the excellent javadoc that comes with almost all "built-int" classes/concepts.

Comment: Javadoc did not help me to find a solution. Try to find a pattern with engineering notation and two fractional digits that works for the two numbers: 12345 and 1234. Either engineering notation does not work or the number of fractional digits is not fix.

Comment: @specializt: Please write it as answer. I will accept it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @specializt: yes google is our friend! 6 years later, this page is one of the top results, instant click ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taken from [this website](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/java/engNotation.html):

```
private final static int PREFIX_OFFSET = 5;
private final static String[] PREFIX_ARRAY = {"f", "p", "n", "µ", "m", "", "k", "M", "G", "T"};

public static String convert(double val, int dp)
{
   // If the value is zero, then simply return 0 with the correct number of dp
   if (val == 0) return String.format("%." + dp + "f", 0.0);

   // If the value is negative, make it positive so the log10 works
   double posVal = (val<0) ? -val : val;
   double log10 = Math.log10(posVal);

   // Determine how many orders of 3 magnitudes the value is
   int count = (int) Math.floor(log10/3);

   // Calculate the index of the prefix symbol
   int index = count + PREFIX_OFFSET;

   // Scale the value into the range 1<=val<1000
   val /= Math.pow(10, count * 3);

   if (index >= 0 && index < PREFIX_ARRAY.length)
   {
      // If a prefix exists use it to create the correct string
      return String.format("%." + dp + "f%s", val, PREFIX_ARRAY[index]);
   }
   else
   {
      // If no prefix exists just make a string of the form 000e000
      return String.format("%." + dp + "fe%d", val, count * 3);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use following:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##0.0E0");
```

Here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

You may find out answer on your question in part of "Science Notation"

> Numbers in scientific notation are expressed as the product of a
>   mantissa and a power of ten, for example, 1234 can be expressed as
>   1.234 x 10^3. The mantissa is often in the range 1.0 <= x < 10.0, but it need not be. DecimalFormat can be instructed to format and parse
>   scientific notation only via a pattern; there is currently no factory
>   method that creates a scientific notation format. In a pattern, the
>   exponent character immediately followed by one or more digit
>   characters indicates scientific notation. Example: "0.###E0" formats
>   the number 1234 as "1.234E3".
>
> The number of digit characters after the exponent character gives the
>   minimum exponent digit count. There is no maximum. Negative exponents
>   are formatted using the localized minus sign, not the prefix and
>   suffix from the pattern. This allows patterns such as "0.###E0 m/s".
>   The minimum and maximum number of integer digits are interpreted
>   together: If the maximum number of integer digits is greater than
>   their minimum number and greater than 1, it forces the exponent to be
>   a multiple of the maximum number of integer digits, and the minimum
>   number of integer digits to be interpreted as 1. The most common use
>   of this is to generate engineering notation, in which the exponent is
>   a multiple of three, e.g., "##0.#####E0". Using this pattern, the
>   number 12345 formats to "12.345E3", and 123456 formats to "123.456E3".
>   Otherwise, the minimum number of integer digits is achieved by
>   adjusting the exponent. Example: 0.00123 formatted with "00.###E0"
>   yields "12.3E-4". The number of significant digits in the mantissa is
>   the sum of the minimum integer and maximum fraction digits, and is
>   unaffected by the maximum integer digits. For example, 12345 formatted
>   with "##0.##E0" is "12.3E3". To show all digits, set the significant
>   digits count to zero. The number of significant digits does not affect
>   parsing. Exponential patterns may not contain grouping separators.

Comment: I want to have engineering notation with 2 fractional digits.

Comment: Please try the pattern with different numbers: 12345 and 1.2 and 12.3

Comment: Do you mean it: "##0.#E0" ?

Comment: 1234 formatted with "##0.#E0" prints out 1.234E3 which are 3 and not 2 fractional digits

Comment: If I correct understand you, problem may be solved by "0.00E0"

Comment: No, "0.00E0" formats 12345 as 1.23E4 which is not engineering notation (that allows multiples of 3 for the mantissa only)

Comment: Try to follow the documentation: 12345 formatted with "##0.##E0" is "12.3E3" -> This is wrong. 12345 formatted with "##0.##E0" is 12.345E3

Comment: I think  it's pattern like "##0.#####E0"

Comment: Btw, you may use it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toEngineeringString()

Comment: 12.345E3 is wrong because the documentation say it should be 12.3E3